# filling HashMap within loop

Tags: java, hashmap

a big doubt! I read that HashMap takes references of objects and doesn't copy values to store data. So if I have something like

```
    HashMap<Integer, Double> map = HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
       Integer key = Integer(i);
       Double value = Double(i*2.0);
       map.put(key, value);
    }
```

What is the result of

```
    map.get(10);
```

? Keys and values are created within the for loop so I suppose that they are deleted at the end of for statement and put(10) give something like null. But I think it's a very annoying behaviour because I can't fill a HashMap with a straighforward for loop... I'm wrong?

Comment: "so I suppose that they are deleted at the end of for statement" - no, they are not. They are no longer accessible via `i` identifier, but they are not deleted.

Comment: The values created in the loop are not destroyed at the end. This is a garbage collected language; objects are recycled when there are no more references to them, and not before.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki So I have some confusion about scope in java... When objects are deleted because they go out of scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in Java, all objects are accessed by reference - there is nothing special about the HashMap here.

Second, all objects are kept in memory until the Garbage collector (GC) decides to destroy them. The GC *may* destroy objects as soon as they are no longer referenced anywhere - it *may not* destroy them if they are still referenced.

In your example :

- After the loop, the object referenced by `map` holds references to the same objects that were referenced by `key`and `value` : those objects cannot be destroyed.
- If, at a later point, you no longer hold any reference to the HashMap object, it may be destroyed by the GC, and the GC may also decide to destroy the key and the value, if they were only referenced by the Hashmap. Note that there is no guarantee given as to *when* garbage collection will occur: it won't necessarily happen immediately.
- You can't do `map.put(10)`, because `HashMap` doesn't have a method with a compatible signature. The only `put` method that exists for `HashMap` expects two parameters.

edit: Since the op corrected `map.put(10)` to `map.get(10)`: it will return a reference to the same object that was briefly referenced by the variable `value` during the "i=10" iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yes, I edited the put that was wrong. Thanks very clear!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you meant to ask what the result of `map.get(10)` is, since `map.put(10)` is not valid. `map.get(10)` would return the Double whose value is `20.0`.

Since the `map` variable is declared outside the for loop, the values you put in the map remain there after the end of the for loop. The keys and values are not deleted at the end of the for loop because the map variable holds references to them.

Comment: ... would return a reference to a Double ... ?

Comment: @AlanStokes I don't understand your question.

Comment: I was proposing a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The key are hold by refrences as (almost)all objects in Java; java won't delete an object which is strongly referenced by another object.

object created in the loop will only be collected if no other object references them after the loop

since you put them into an hashmap, java will keep them around

note also that put(10, ...) actually is put(new Integer(10),  ...) thanks to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)